# DocuSign For Salesforce CCTM and CCRM

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating an Salesforce opportunity custom button that is intended to automatically set the recipients sourced from opportunity contact roles. I only want recipients included in the envelope that have a role of 'Approver' I am using the parameters of CCTM and CCRM. When the envelope loads in Salesforce, the recipients are null.

```
CRL='Email~frasuy@email.com;FirstName~DocuSign;LastName~ProofOfConcept;Role~Signer2;RoutingOrder~2';
CCTM='Approver~Signer';
CCRM='Approver~Signer 1';
```

I am using CRL so I can include a recipient who will never be a contact role and will also be the second signer. This is working just fine.

Will the CCTM and CCRM parameters only work when using the DST parameter which I am currently not using since the document being signed is not using a DocuSign template? Is that why my recipient list is null? The document being signed is created upstream in BigMachines which has imbedded DocuSign custom tags.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using CRL as part of the custom button and still want to call the contacts in the Opportunity, the CRL needs to have `LoadDefaultContacts~1`.

Try something like this:

```
CRL='Email~frasuy@email.com;FirstName~DocuSign;LastName~ProofOfConcept;Role~Signer2;RoutingOrder~2,LoadDefaultContacts~1';
```

Comment: In using the CRL parameter the explicit role that is being passed is not being respected. CRL='Email~frasuy@email.com;FirstName~Any;LastName~Signer;Role~Legal;RoutingOrder~2,LoadDefaultContacts~1'; The role that is loaded is always the first entry the (Salesforce) DocuSignAdmin | Envelope settings. In my case the first role is customer so even though CRL is set to pass Role~Legal; customer is being used. Missing something?

Comment: The recipient being passed in CRL is a hard coded recipient and is not a Contact Role associated with the opportunity.